# Installing P3DFFT

Tags: software-installation

I am installing P3DFFT in ubuntu. I downloaded the ".tar.gz" file for it and extracted. Then used the "./configure" command. The configure gave the following error, 
" configure:error:You must choose to use either ESSL or FTTW "
I have istalled the FTTW lib before P3DFFT. Please help me on this error.

Thanks

Comment: Please run `./configure --help` to know the options `--enable-fftw` and `--with-fftw` .

Comment: ... although there appears to be an additional wrinkle that the `./configure` script is hardwired to look in `$with-fftw/lib64` rather than the multiarch-aware location `$with-fftw/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` for example

Answer (score 1):

As you do not specify your Ubuntu version I tested the method below on two supported LTS versions - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

---

Install FFTW-related developer packages and build-dependencies. Do not forget to enable source code repositories in *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) before you proceed.
Then run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libfftw3-dev libfftw3-mpi-dev libopenmpi-dev gfortran
sudo apt-get build-dep -y libfftw3-dev libfftw3-mpi-dev
```

Download and extract P3DFFT package:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/sdsc/p3dfft/archive/v2.7.6.tar.gz
tar -xf v2.7.6.tar.gz
cd p3dfft-2.7.6/
```

As it was [already written by @steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037360/66509):

> The first thing to note is that the argument to `--with-fftw`
>   must be the top level path to the FFTW3 header files and libraries. So
>   for example if the headers are in `/usr/include` and the libraries are
>   under `/usr/lib` (the default, when package `libfftw3-dev` is
>   installed from the Ubuntu repository), the value should be given as
>   `--with-fftw=/usr`
>
> The additional issue in this case is that the provided configure
>   script appears to be hard-wired to look in only the `lib` and `lib64`
>   subdirectories:
>
> ```
>    3315         if test -e $withfftw/lib/libfftw3.a ; then
>    3316                 FFTW_INC="-I$withfftw/include"
>    3317 
>    3318                 FFTW_LIB="$withfftw/lib/libfftw3.a"
>    3319 
>    3320         elif test -e $withfftw/lib64/libfftw3.a ; then
>    3321                 FFTW_INC="-I$withfftw/include"
>    3322 
>    3323                 FFTW_LIB="$withfftw/lib64/libfftw3.a"
>    3324 
>    3325         else
>    3326                 as_fn_error $? "libfftw3.a was not found in given location!" "$LINENO" 5
>    3327         fi
> ```
>
> The use of a `lib64` subdirectory is an old convention that pre-dates
>   Debian's [Multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch) framework - the modern location for 64-bit
>   libraries would be `lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

So you need to patch the *configure* script. You can do it with commands below:

```
sed -i 's/\$withfftw\/include/\/usr\/include/g' configure
sed -i 's/\$withfftw\/lib64\//\$withfftw\//g' configure
sed -i 's/\$withfftw\/lib\//\$withfftw\//g' configure
```

Then run new patched *configure* script with correct options:

```
./configure --enable-fftw --with-fftw=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Then run the compilation and installation:

```
make
sudo make install
```