# P3DFFT installation - "libfftw3.a not found"

Tags: software-installation

I used the command

```
 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --enable-gnu --enable-fftw --with-fftw=/home/kiran1209/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/.libs/ LDflags="-lmpi_f90 -lmpi_f77"
```

( Is the command correct?)

but after running for some time it gives the error

```
configure: error: libfftw3.a was not found in given location!
```

The file exists but with different extension `.la`. What should I do about this error?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: P3DFFT : `./configure` refuses to recognize libfftw3.a in **any** location. Also /lib/ (and /lib64/) suggested by @steeldriver here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036959/installing-p3dfft (Your previous P3DFFT thread) ... See `configure`, lines 3315 .. 3326. (Ubuntu 18.04 was used for my tests.)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is that the argument to `--with-fftw` must be the top level path to the FFTW3 header files and libraries. So for example if the headers are in `/usr/include` and the libraries are under `/usr/lib` (the default, when package `libfftw3-dev` is installed from the Ubuntu repository), the value should be given as `--with-fftw=/usr`

The additional issue in this case is that the provided configure script appears to be hard-wired to look in only the `lib` and `lib64` subdirectories:

```
   3315         if test -e $withfftw/lib/libfftw3.a ; then
   3316                 FFTW_INC="-I$withfftw/include"
   3317 
   3318                 FFTW_LIB="$withfftw/lib/libfftw3.a"
   3319 
   3320         elif test -e $withfftw/lib64/libfftw3.a ; then
   3321                 FFTW_INC="-I$withfftw/include"
   3322 
   3323                 FFTW_LIB="$withfftw/lib64/libfftw3.a"
   3324 
   3325         else
   3326                 as_fn_error $? "libfftw3.a was not found in given location!" "$LINENO" 5
   3327         fi
```

The use of a `lib64` subdirectory is an old convention that pre-dates Debian's [Multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch) framework - the modern location for 64-bit libraries would be `lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

There *may* be a 'clean' way to re-configure that (perhaps using `autoreconf`) however I don't know it - if you don't mind using a quick'n'dirty fix, then it should be sufficient to fix the search location using `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's:lib64:lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:g' configure
```

and then re-run `./configure`

Answer (score 1):

> Ref. @steeeldriver: sed -i.bak 's:lib64:lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:g'
>   configure

The `sed` editing is OK with the first configuring. But `make` generates a new file `configure`.

Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 build example:

```
cd /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.a

cd /usr/bin/
sudo ln -s aclocal-1.15 aclocal-1.14
sudo ln -s automake-1.15 automake-1.14

git clone https://github.com/sdsc/p3dfft.git
cd p3dfft/
./configure --enable-fftw --with-fftw=/usr && make
```

No errors, 16.04 or 18.04 .

---

EDIT : Using your new options, ref. [make: *** [all] Error 2 while installing P3DFFT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037638/make-all-error-2-while-installing-p3dfft#comment1689339_1037638)

```
./configure --enable-gnu --enable-fftw --with-fftw=/usr --enable-estimate --enable-measure --enable-patient
```

... and using the default fftw3 : No errors. Neither with `p3dfft-2.7.6` or `git clone https://github.com/sdsc/p3dfft.git`

---

Using fftw3 in /usr/local/: `fftw3_3.3.7.orig.tar.xz` http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fftw3/fftw3_3.3.7.orig.tar.xz

```
cd fftw-3.3.7/
./configure --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-threads --enable-openmp --enable-mpi --prefix=/usr/local
make && sudo make install
```

And p3dfft/:

```
./configure --enable-gnu --enable-fftw --with-fftw=/usr/local --enable-estimate --enable-measure --enable-patient
make
```

No errors, 16.04 or 18.04, except for `cannot find -lmpichf90` : {libmpichf90.a, libmpichf90.so} i.e. **if the driver test is run**. 
No {libmpichf90.a, libmpichf90.so} in the default Ubuntu packages.

Comment: I used the script : "./configure --enable-fftw --with-fftw=/usr/local FC=gfortran CC=gcc". It ran and then the "make" command. But it gives the following error ,
Makefile:345: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Kiran Jadhav : Drop the `FC=gfortran CC=gcc` to avoid running the tests → Read my answer : ... ... » **if the driver test is run** « .... ....